# "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by" error.How to redirect upon successful submission of the form

Tags: php, header

My code below uses header for redirection upon successful submission of the form and checks if all error variables are set to NULL for redirecting to another php page.
Please help me out as I have tried many ways but none seems to work for conditional redirection.

```
<?php
$proName=$proNameErr=$email=$emailErr=$catErr='';
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
if (empty($_POST["proName"])) {
$proNameErr = "Product name is required";
}
else if(!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9 .&]+$/i',$_POST['proName'])){
$proNameErr = "Invalid product Name";
}

else{
$proName = test_input($_POST["proName"]);
}

if($_POST['cat']==0)
{
$catErr="please select an option";
}
else
{
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
$email = "";
}
else{
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$emailErr = "Invalid email format";
}

}
if($proNameErr=='' &&  $emailErr=='' && $catErr=='')
{
header("Location: addMedia.php", true, 302);
die();
}
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>ADD Product</h1>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"   method="post"  autocomplete="on">
Product Name: <input type="text" name="proName" placeholder="Product  Name" maxlength="35" size="40" required value="<?php echo $proName?>">*
<span class="error"><?php echo $proNameErr;?></span><br><br>

Category: <select name="cat" id="cat" size="1" required>
<option value=0>Select...</option>
<option value=1>John</option>
<option value=2>Paul</option>
<option value=3>Ringo</option>
<option value=4>George</option>
<option value=5>ram</option>
<option value=6>rahim</option>
</select>*<span class="error"><?php echo $catErr;?></span><br><br>

Email Address: <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo  $email?>"> <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Well, something in your code (or included files) does send some output before you call the header function. you must find out what/where and prevent that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have outputted something to the browser before header call. It cannot be exact copy of your code that you show us. Check:

- is there any html before php opening tag
- is there any whitespace before php opening tag
- is another php script included with echo before that script
- is the coding utf8 with BOM?

Those are possible reasons of your error.

Answer (score 0):

Output buffering is your friend in this case.
At the top of each page ( or at the very least, the page in question here ) add

```
ob_start();

/* the rest of the code */

/*and at the end*/

ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Hm, wouldn't it make more sense to find the cause of the problem instead of layering a workaround on top? Apart from that: why do you flush at the end? There is not output meant to be sent to the client...